# Check session before making oData calls - HANA Cloud Portal

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I am working with HCP Portal SAPUI5 apps. I need to check the session before every data call is made to the backend so I can redirect the user back to the logon page.

In the HANA Cloud documentation, the below code is provided:

```js
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, jqXHR) {
  if (jqXHR.getResponseHeader("com.sap.cloud.security.login")) {
    alert("Session is expired, page shall be reloaded.");
    jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });
  }
});
```

But the above code only works for Ajax calls. I am not sure if the same works for odata as well. We want to redirect the user in every scenario after session expiry.
Is there a direct method to achieve it both for data calls and Ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the *success callback function* for the value of the HTTP response header `"com.sap.cloud.security.login"`:

```
  sap.ui.getCore().getModel().read("/SOME_ENTITYSet", {

     success: function(odata, response) {
       if (response.headers["com.sap.cloud.security.login"] === "login-request") {
          // Timeout handling
       } else {  
          // Process data in argument odata  
       }
     },

     error: function(error) {
       if (response.headers["com.sap.cloud.security.login"] === "login-request") {
          // Timeout handling
       } else {  
          // Show error message (for non-timeout errors)
       }         
     }
  });
```

If have seen cases in which upon a timeout the *success callback function* has been called; but I have also seen cases in which the *error callback function* has been called; therefore I check in both cases for a timeout.

The timeout handling might be a dialog telling the user that the session has timed out and asking him if he wants to restart the application.